# NAS detected on Windows 10 but not showing under Network

Tags: windows, network-shares, nas

I have a MyBookLiveDuo NAS that is working and configured correctly (It was working on Windows 8.1 before I updated).

After I updated it simply do not show under Network on Windows Explorer. I can access its configuration page through the browser and it's on the same workgroup as my PC.

I can ping the IP addres and I get 4/4 responses: ping 192.168.0.100

If I try to ping like this it does not work: ping \192.168.0.100

My network has Network discovery enabled and File and printer sharing enabled.

This is my ipconfig /all results:

```
Configuração de IP do Windows

   Nome do host. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : RB-DESKTOP
   Sufixo DNS primário . . . . . . . . . . . . :
   Tipo de nó. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : híbrido
   Roteamento de IP ativado. . . . . . . . . . : não
   Proxy WINS ativado. . . . . . . . . . . . . : não

Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet 2:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-00
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sim
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::b578:8124:53a:6a79%8(Preferencial)
   Endereço IPv4 de Configuração Automática. . : 169.254.106.121(Preferencial)
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                                 fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                                 fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS em Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Habilitado

Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : F4-6D-04-44-1B-D4
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sim
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::79c5:9174:9a50:c226%14(Preferencial)
   Endereço IPv4. . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.103(Preferencial)
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Concessão Obtida. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sexta-feira, 10 de julho de 2015 21:28:06
   Concessão Expira. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sexta-feira, 10 de julho de 2015 23:28:06
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   IAID de DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 250899716
   DUID de Cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-2F-83-77-F4-6D-04-44-1B-D4
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS em Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Habilitado

Adaptador Ethernet Conexão de Rede Bluetooth:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-26-83-16-2B-AC
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sim
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim

Adaptador de túnel isatap.{4E38D948-3AA9-4398-8ABD-D3ACBD876CB3}:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Não
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim

Adaptador de túnel Conexão Local* 2:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Não
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
   Endereço IPv6 . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:3829:274d:373e:5261(Preferencial)
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::3829:274d:373e:5261%2(Preferencial)
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : ::
   IAID de DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 251658240
   DUID de Cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-2F-83-77-F4-6D-04-44-1B-D4
   NetBIOS em Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Desabilitado

Adaptador de túnel isatap.{FEC5A884-5C7E-44B6-A157-15564FE059DC}:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Não
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
```

Comment: try a run box command   \\192.168.0.100   what error do you get?

Comment: @Moab Windows cannot access \\192.168.0.100 Error Code: 0x80070035

Comment: You running any 3rd party AV or firewall?

Comment: Be sure file and print sharing is on the allowed apps and features firewall list and is ticked.

Comment: @moab I'm using Windows Firewall but I've disabled it to be sure it's not blocking anything

Comment: Sounds like your Duo no longer has CIFS running.

Comment: @SilverlightFox I don't think there's any problem with the NAS since it's still available to the other computers on the network